# Ignoring whitespace in Ruby with x regex modifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm going through a Ruby tutorial on Rubymonk and the problem statement goes like this: *Given a sentence, return true if the sentence is a palindrome. Ignore whitespace and cases of characters.*

Rubymonk gives me the following solution using `gsub`,

```
  def palindrome?(sentence)
      downcase_stripped_sentence = sentence.downcase.gsub(" ", "")
      downcase_stripped_sentence  ==  downcase_stripped_sentence.reverse
    end

    palindrome?("Never odd or even")
```

but I was wondering if I could complete the task using the `//x` regex modifier.
What do you think?

Comment: Did you try? What did it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use the `/x` Regexp flag. That *only* applies to the pattern being generated itself, not to the Regular Expression engine's matching of strings.

You'll have to preprocess the string being matched if you want to ignore characters, which is what `gsub(" ", "")` is doing.

Personally, I'd use `delete(' ')` or `tr(' ', '')` as either is faster than `gsub` used that way:

```
require 'fruity'

STRING = ('a'..'z').to_a * ' '

compare do
  use_tr { STRING.tr(' ', '') }
  use_delete { STRING.delete(' ') }
  use_gsub { STRING.gsub(' ', '') }
end
# >> Running each test 4096 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> use_delete is similar to use_tr
# >> use_tr is faster than use_gsub by 5x ± 1.0
```

Comment: Would you give me a simple example of how the the /x Regexp flag is used?

Comment: No, because this is very well documented in the Regexp documentation and multiple places on the internet. Please take it upon yourself to do the research first. Stack Overflow is not a replacement for trying and teaching yourself.

Comment: Here is the documentation for /x, called "free space mode": https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Free-Spacing+Mode+and+Comments.  It has an example.  I have 27 years of experience, have used this feature many times, and still cannot remember the exact syntax or name, so VaVa don't feel bad that you asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by using an [eval](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/eval), but, in my opinion, string eval is a pure evil.

Function with gsub looks pretty good.

Comment: String eval gets a bad rap. Ease off.

Comment: There's a time and place to use `eval`. If you own the code that generates the string being evaluated, then it's perfectly safe, at least as long as you're not trying to attack your own system. If the string being eval'd comes from an external, untrusted or unknown source, then it's much less safe and `eval` probably should be avoided. As for the answer itself, it's low quality and needs a much better explanation for why eval should be avoided and "Function with gsub looks pretty good." should be expanded and explained. See "[answer]".